# react-native-firebase preload admob ad before showing the ad?

Tags: react-native-firebase

I'd like to preload the admob ad.

I'm showing the ad when user hits the backbutton in a modal.
But the ad loads too slow, and user leaves the screen before even seeing the ad.

Is there a way to preload the admob ad?